# Using Component as dialog ref but not always

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, material-dialog

So I have a component which is sometimes used as a dialog ref and sometimes used normally outside of a dialog.

For example:

- A form with a yes or no answer

Now sometimes I render this component inside a chat component (which is not a dialog) and sometimes I render this component by itself as a dialog.

Now, the issue is that I'm using:

```
  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<PaymentFormComponent>
  ) {
  }
```

in the constructor as I want to be able to manually close the dialog when an event happens:

```
    if (this.dialogRef) {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
```

Now this is causing an issue when I'm using the component outside a dialog, because it saying this

`ERROR Error: "No provider for MdDialogRef!"`

Is it possible to only have this provided optionally and have it be null when it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Optional decorator will fix your issue

```
    @Optional()private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<PaymentFormComponent>
  ) {
  }
```